# Как связать интерфейс с его реализацией?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

У меня есть массив в котором ключ - имя интерфейса, а значение - его реализация.

`['Mailer' => 'PhpMailer']`.

Мне потребовалась реализация интерфейса:

```
function Foo(Mailer $mailer){
    //...
}
```

**Как объяснить что реализацией интерфейса Mailer является класс PhpMailer?**

Для этого нужно использовать spl_autoload_register?
Приведите примитивный пример как при требовании интерфейса Mailer, возвращать его реализацию: PhpMailer

p.s. [пример работы в laravel](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/container#%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: Дык у вас же есть массив, где реализацией интерфейса Mailer является класс PhpMailer. Что вам ещё нужно?

Comment: Не понятно, что вам нужно. Если нужно в функции проверять, какой класс в переменной $mailer - то используем `get_class($mailer)`, если же в функции Foo() аргументом должен быть только класс PhpMailer, то так и пишем `Foo(PhpMailer $mailer)`.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh мне нужно что бы в `function Foo(Mailer $mailer)` Mailer воспринимался (и соответственно сравнивался) как PhpMailer. При этом что бы я ничего более не писал. То есть ассоциация интерфейса с реализацией.

Comment: @ArchDemon сейчас это просто массив. И он ничего не значит и ничего не делает. Просто представление моей задачи. Выше я объяснил что мне требуется реализовать.

Comment: Приведите пример того, что у вас не работает, но вы хотите, чтобы работало как вам нужно. Потому что, если честно, нихрена не понятно, что же вам нужно. Потому что звучит так, как будто вы не знаете `class PhpMailer implements Mailer`

Comment: @ArchDemon кажется я не правильно понял смысл контейнера в laravel. Я думал что используя магию пони он преобразует Mailer в PhpMailer в заданных неймспейсах. Но нет. Видимо это не совсем так, а годится только для того, что бы регистрировать (или "помнить") соответствия классов интерфейсам в определенных местах программы. Что бы можно было доставать имя класса в зависимости от namespace так: `Container::getImplement('Mailer')` (тут это вернуло бы класс PhpMailer)

Comment: Вам стоит почитать про dependency injection и другие шаблоны проектирования

Comment: @ArchDemon читал. Но разве DI работает не так? Можете привести примитивный пример реализации DI? Вы бы могли написать это в ответ, я бы отметил это как правильный ответ. Ну или дайте хотя бы ссылку на простое объяснение реализации DI, я был бы рад